# Javascript Function Not Being Called after dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I have a weird issue that i am hoping someone can help resolve.

**Problem**

When i load html dynamically via .load() function, if any aspect of html in the loaded fragment tries to access the javascript query functions in original HTML page, it doesn't work. Example code below:

Main HTML page (main.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
<!--javascript load functions etc... standard header stuff -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="dynamic_section_fragment"></div>
<a href="javascript:" onclick="loadFragment()">Load Fragment</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        // <![CDATA[
function loadFragment() {
            $("#dynamic_section_fragment").load("/api/fragment/");
        };

$(".checkvalue").click(function () {
            $.getJSON("/api/checkvalue", {term: $(this).attr('value')}, function () {
                console.info("submitted for checking");
            })
        });
        // ]]>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

FRAGMENT File (fragment.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head lang="en">

    </head>
    <body>
<div th:fragment="check_value">
    <br/>
Check the value in the attribute field   
<br/>
<a href="javascript:" th:attr="value='123'" class="checkvalue">Check This<a/> 
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

SPRING MVC Controller Method

```
@RequestMapping("/api/checkvalue")
public String getFragment(Model model) {
return "fragment :: check_value";
}
```

So a run down of actions:

-Main.html page loads

-User clicks on Load Fragment hyperlink

-Javascript dynamically loads the relevant fragment into the div

-User clicks on Check This hyperlink, **nothing happens**

Is there something i am missing or something i need to be aware?

It is as if Thymeleaf has preregistered all the possible scenarios of events and doesn't allow any others.
Only way i have been able to get it to work is by injecting the "checkvalue" javascript within the fragment, which as you can agree is a bad way of doing things.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: is the fragment loaded asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the click event listener to all existing objects with the `checkvalue` class.

```
$(".checkvalue").click(function ()
```

What you rather wish to do (to make the click event apply to all the existing and any new added, dynamically) is to set a event on a parent in the dom tree (parent both to the existing and to all that will be added).
In your case, the `body` tag would probably be the safe bet.

The following should suffice:

```
$('body').on('click', '.checkvalue', function() { ...
```

Simplified, the code will apply a listener on the `body` element instead of the `.checkvalue` objects, and whenever a object with the `.checkvalue` class is clicked (wether dynamically or statically loaded), the event will fire.

---

*edit*
I would also suggest that you, in your javascript, don't use jquery before you know for certain that it is loaded.
The jquery lib have a way of fixing this for you, by using the [`$( document ).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)  function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // All jquery dependant code here.
});
```

Comment: Fantastic. I'd buy you beer coz this was doing my head in (I'm just coming back to javascript after exceptionally long absence).

Comment: Simple but very important note. Thank you @Jite.